# How to create Urbanspoon pickerview on ios8?

Tags: uipickerview

I want to create uipickerview like picker in application [Urbanspoon](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/urbanspoon-restaurant-food/id284708449?mt=8).
How do I increase time of spinning?

I want to make the spin duration longer

```
-(IBAction)spin:(id)sender{
  [pickerView selectRow: (arc4random() % [myArray count])+1000 inComponent: 0 animated: YES];}
```

Comment: Please update the question to show your code, then maybe somebody can show you how to modify it to achieve what you need

Comment: @AlexS can u help me?